# ros-fuerte-pcl missing dependency libmysqlclient_16

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-fuerte, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working on releasing a stack into fuerte.  It depends on pcl and currently when I try to compile I am getting the following error:

Linking CXX executable ../bin/pointcloud_snapshot
/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_surface.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual@libmysqlclient_16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

After doing some web research I found a link to this ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5415

While I believe that the fix (sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev) will work to get it to install properly on my machine I need to make sure that for a generic install my code can be released.  Is there something I need to do or should I open a ticket.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33974/ros-fuerte-pcl-missing-dependency-libmysqlclient_16/) by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out I was having dependency issues.  If you see this error you should make sure that your dependencies, libmysqlclient_16 and libmysqlclient-dev have been updated.

If using ubuntu/debian, make sure to check that the update repositories are enabled by checking that `/etc/apt/sources.list` has something like:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe main multiverse
```

with lucid replaced by whatever ubuntu release you have.

Or by checking in Synaptic in settings>repositores>updates>recommended updates checkbox.

---

Originally posted by [Sarah Osentoski](https://answers.ros.org/users/701/sarah-osentoski/) with karma: 136 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case (Ros electric, Ubuntu 10.04), it was necessary to install manually the pacakges for mysql-common, libmysqlclient16, libmysqlclient-dev and libmysqlclient16-dev instead of using a pacakage manager.

---

Originally posted by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) with karma: 195 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-10-11**:
when you say manually are you saying specific versions were needed? Any idea what versions they were?